# How to Create a dynamic class and add it to project

Tags: c#, reflection, c#-4.0, dynamic, dynamicobject

How I can Create a dynamic class and add it to the project(creating from)?

can I create class in **Build and Rebuild** of my project? I mean can I handle **Build and Rebuild** events in my project?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a static file to your project, say dynamicclass.cs and modify its content in `Project/Properties/BuildEvents/Pre-build event command line`

Answer (score 0):

You can create dynamic assemblies and then use reflector or smoother tool to create source for them.  You can then add them to your project using a macro or addin or modify the csproj file.